# Using Fiddler to troubleshoot classic asp file calling web service

Tags: web-services, asp-classic, fiddler

I am having trouble debugging a classic asp file in which I call a .NET web service.  I am hoping that I can use Fiddler to see why the HTTP request to the web service is returning a 'Bad Request' error.  I have a console application to request the classic asp file. Within the classic asp file I call the web service.  When I run Fiddler, I see the request to the asp file but not the request to the web service.  There is just one line in Fiddler with the asp file request.

Any suggestions or advice to troubleshoot the asp file would be appreciated.

Below is the code to sends a GET request to the web service.
The response in the console application is:
   Status: 200
   Status text: OK

But the call to the web service does not appear in Fiddler, only the call to the asp file.  The web service and asp file are on different servers.

Shouldn't I see this call to the web service on Fiddler?

I want to debug a POST request but first I must learn how to use Fiddler. :)

This is my console application that calls the asp page:

```
Uri aspPServiceUri = new Uri("http://<serverNameAndPath>/FirstPage.asp?<parameters>;");
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(aspPServiceUri);
httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";               
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
string strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(strResponse);
reader.Close();
```

This the asp file:

```
Set httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
URL = "http://<serverName>:<port>/PService/PService.Paging.svc?WSDL"
httpRequest.Open "GET", URL, False 
httpRequest.Send()
Dim strResult
Dim strStatusText
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
strStatusText = "Status: " & httpRequest.status & vbCrLf & "Status text: " & httpRequest.statusText
Response.Write(vbCrLf & strStatusText & vbCrLf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using IIS 7+ or a relatively recent version of IIS Express, add the following to your web.config file. If you don't already have a web.config, then add one.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy autoDetect="False" bypassonlocal="False" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="False" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

This configures Fiddler as a proxy, so all HTTP requests from the web app will be routed through Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try that.

Comment: Sorry it has been so long.  I was pulled to another project.  I tried that suggestion and still only see the call to the asp file on Fiddler. Not the call to the web service